# Problem pushing docker image from azure pipeline

Tags: docker, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have an azure devops pipeline.

```
    trigger:
- master

resources:
- repo: self

steps:
  - task: Docker@2
    displayName: Login to ACR
    inputs:
      command: login
      containerRegistry: myDockerHubConnection

  - task: Docker@2
    displayName: Build an image
    inputs:
        command: build
        arguments: --build-arg git_personal_token=ghp_MYTOKEN
        dockerfile: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/Dockerfile'
        tags: tag1

  - task: Docker@2
    displayName: Push image
    inputs:
        repository: 'crooksey201/ngx-int-api' #dockerhubAccountName/repoName
        command: push
        tags: tag1
```

This builds my image fine, but on the push stage, I get the error:

```
##[error]An image does not exist locally with the tag: ***/ngx-int-api
```

And in the list of docker images I just get:

```
REPOSITORY       TAG         IMAGE ID       CREATED                  SIZE
<none>           <none>      f705e0d37a95   Less than a second ago   1.76GB
```

This image has no tag which I am confused about, as I think I have specified the tags correctly in my pipeline, can anyone spot my error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was relating to the quotes around `repository` I updated a few things, but a working YAML is:

```
trigger:
- master

resources:
- repo: self

variables:
  tag: '$(Build.BuildId)'
steps:
  - task: Docker@2
    displayName: Login to ACR
    inputs:
      command: login
      containerRegistry: DockerHubConnectionName

  - task: Docker@2
    displayName: Build an image
    inputs:
        containerRegistry: DockerHubConnectionName
        repository: mydockerhubusername/my-repo
        command: build
        arguments: --build-arg git_personal_token=ghp_MYTOKEN
        dockerfile: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/Dockerfile'
        tags: |
          $(tag)
  - task: Docker@2
    displayName: push the image
    inputs:
        containerRegistry: DockerHubConnectionName
        repository: mydockerhubusername/my-repo
        command: push
        tags: |
          $(tag)
```

Answer (score 0):

some of the inputs of the task Docker@2 in your example are [not documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/docker?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml), and the `imageName:` might be `repository:`.

Comment: I updated my YAML file to remove deprecated decorators, even with the updates it shows no parsing errors and the output is the same.

Comment: I have awarded the bounty as I appreciate the time taken to look over this and refer to some deprecated inputs.